# How can I adjust the amount of emails showed in Notification center?

Tags: email, notifications, ios

In iOS9's Notification Center, I have hundreds and hundreds of emails listed all the way back to 3 days ago.

I tried to find a limitation in the "Notifications" Settings page, Ideally to restrict the emails to either the last 2 days or to the last 15 or 20 emails received, but couldn't find a solution for this there...

[image]

Comment: Not an answer, but I have the same question. In the previous version of iOS there was a "Show in notification center" option that doesn't seem to be there anymore. Wondering how to get this back because I don't want 30 emails in my notification center.